# Xcode Search History

Tags: xcode, macos, search, xcode4.3

A feature common to a lot of other IDEs and text-editors is search history, i.e. the ability to view (and use again) previous searches for strings in source files. I can't find this functionality in Xcode, am I missing something, or is it really missing from Xcode? I'm using Xcode 4.3 on OS X Lion.

Comment: A *lot* of functionality is missing from Xcode. I am not surprised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both file search and project search has a small down arrow with recent searches.

[image: file search]
[image: project search]

Comment: Oops, don't know how I missed that. Although the search history seems to be cleared if you sneeze, that's probably how. Seriously, it's cleared for a file if you switch to another file and for the project if you close it.

Comment: Yeah it seams to not be preserved if you close the project or file.

Comment: this history of search tokens evidently is never shown unless you have first toggled between : Style, from Textual to Regular Expressions - xcode feature usage invokes added functionality

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'm hoping someone can tell me why in Xcode 12.4 (and recent previous versions too), I can't seem to get more than *one* search-history item no matter what I do.  In other words, if I do two free-text searches in a row, only the last one shows up in the list of "recent searches" in the "Find" UI. Anyone seen this?   There's no limit setting in Xcode settings. Maybe it inherits from my Mac OS (Catalina) system-wide settings somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to increase the number of items in these lists?